# PhP/MySQL: how to dynamically change my (large and always changing) database

Tags: php, mysql, database, while-loop, percentile

**Scenario**

I have a MySQL database with 10.000 rows. Setup of the database:

```
ID   UniqueKey   Name     Url           Score   ItemValue
1    5Zvr3       Google   google.com    13      X
2    46cfG       Radio    radio.com     -20     X
3    2fg64       Yahoo    yahoo.com     5       X
.... etc etc etc
```

As you can see, each item has a **score**. The score is constantly changing. Google may have a score of 13 now, but tomorrow it may be 80, or -50.

**What I want:**

I want to create a system that creates a hierarchy in my current database, based on the **score** of the items. Right now I'm thinking about **percentile ranks**, meaning that the highest scoring items will be close to 100%, and the lowest scoring items will be close to 0%. For this I created some code that will try to achieve what is shown here: http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/introbook/sbk14m.htm

[image]

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM database order by Score";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $woow = $row['Score'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE Score = $woow";
    $resultnew = $conn->query($sql);
    $somanythesame = $resultnew->num_rows;

    $itemPercentile = ( ($count/$result->num_rows + 0.5*$somanythesame/$result->num_rows) * 100 );

    $rowID = $row['ID'];
    $sql2 = "UPDATE database SET itemValue = $itemPercentile WHERE ID = $rowID";
    $conn->query($sql2);
    $count++;
}
```

**This works, but for one problem it does not:** There are many items in my database, many with the **same score**. To illustrate my problem, here is a very simple 10-row database with only the Scores:

**Scores**

```
-10
0
0
0
10
20
20
30
40
50
```

The problem with my code is that it doesn't give the same percentile for the items with the **same Score**, because it takes in account **all** previous rows for the calculation, including the ones with the same Score.

**So, for the 2nd, 3rd and 4th item with a `Score of 0`, it should be like this: `(1/10 + 0.5*1/10) * 100`. Problem is, that for the 3rd item it will do `(2/10 + 0.5*1/10) * 100` and the 4th item it will do `(3/10 + 0.5*1/10) * 100`.**

Then, for the 5th item with a score of 10, it **should** do `(4/10 + 0.5*1/10) * 100`. This is going well; only not for the items with te same score.

---

I'm not sure if I explained this well, I find it hard to put my problem in the right words. If you have any questions, let me know! Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain an "identical count" (`$icount`) variable that tracks the number of items with an identical score and a "current score" (`$score`) that tracks the current score.

```
$icount = 0;
$score = null;
```

Increment `$icount` instead of `$count` when `$woow == $score` (identical value check).  Otherwise, add it to your `$count` and increment, and then reset the `$icount` value to 0.

```
if ($woow == $score) {
    $icount++;
} else {
    $count += $icount + 1;
    $icount = 0;
}
```

Finally, set your `$score` value to the latest `$woow` for testing in the next iteration of the loop:

```
$score = $woow;
```

This will allow items with the same Score to have the same `$count` value, while incrementing an additional `$icount` times when a new `$score` is found.

Your final code will look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM database order by Score";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count = 0;
$icount = 0;
$score = null;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $woow = $row['Score'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE Score = $woow";
    $resultnew = $conn->query($sql);
    $somanythesame = $resultnew->num_rows;

    $itemPercentile = ( ($count/$result->num_rows + 0.5*$somanythesame/$result->num_rows) * 100 );

    $rowID = $row['ID'];
    $sql2 = "UPDATE database SET itemValue = $itemPercentile WHERE ID = $rowID";
    $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($woow == $score) {
        $icount++;
    } else {
        $count += $icount + 1;
        $icount = 0;
    }
    $score = $woow;
}
```

Comment: Updated to fix score persistence on loop iteration

Comment: Thanks @StevenMoseley! Sorry for the late reply, but this answer is really nice! It only works partially though. Right now, the first item with `score 0` has a `count = 2` value, and the 2nd, 3rd and 4th item with `score 0` has a `count = 3` value. Is there any chance you can help me with that? Right now it's getting a little too complicated for me... Thanks in advance! You're a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

You can change $sql query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT *,count(*) FROM database group by Score order by Score";
```

In this case, you fetch score with counts and no more select needed in the while loop.

Even you can select Percentile in MySQL query:

```
 Select t2.* , @fb as N , ((t2.fb1 + 0.5 * t2.fw)/@fb*100) as percentile from (
      Select t1.* , (@fb := @fb + t1.fw) as fb1 from (
           Select score,count(*) as fw From tablename group by score order by score ASC
           ) as t1
      ) as t2
```

I think this query returns most of columns which you may needs to check results.